# BCrypt vs. SHA-256 for the Future of the Web

Tags: grails, web-applications, encryption, passwords, cryptography

I have a Grails web-application right now that uses SHA-256 with unique salts to store the user's password in my database. I recently upgraded the web-app to the most current version of the Spring Security plugin(2.0RC2) for Grails(2.3.4). The new plugin uses BCrypt by default. My question is, which one is better and why would they make the switch to BCrypt. I've read articles on people who love BCrypt and people that hate BCrypt. One immediate pro I see is that salting is built into the algorithm, so I wouldn't have to store the salts separately. I also noticed that you can set the iterations on the SHA-256. From what I read, a lot of people like BCrypt because you can set the iterations for it as well, but how does that differ from setting the iterations of SHA-256? One blog said that PBKDF2 was a far superior choice because it's been tested. But I also hear the same thing about BCrypt...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no "they", it's just me :)

You can set the iteration count for SHA-256, but it doesn't slow things down like increasing the logrounds value for bcrypt. You can make bcrypt very slow, and this does make logging in slower for the users, but that's not a big deal in general. But it does make it much more expensive to brute force hashed passwords if your database is compromised.

Comment: In the end the cost factor for bcrypt and the iteration count of PBKDF2 simply define a constant time slow down. That bcrypt uses a logarithmic scale does not matter much - as long as the iteration count is high enough, PBKDF2 can match the slow down. bcrypt's cost factor may be easier for the user to understand, but it should not matter for security (given that c - the iteration count in PBKDF - can have a high enough value for a given implementation, of course).

Answer (score 6):

Both bcrypt and PBKDF2 are well known algorithms. As long as you use them within bounds, either one of them should be OK.

You can of course use SHA-256 to create a similar scheme using an iteration count and a salt. But unless you come up with your own security proof, tests, community etc. etc. you should be using a known or standardized algorithm if it is available.

PBKDF2 does use a hash algorithm underneath, so it can be configured for SHA-256 - if the implementation allows it.

---

The only other choice at the moment is scrypt. scrypt is arguably safer because it relies on a relatively large amount of memory. Because of this, scrypt is harder to parallelize, e.g. using a vector machine such as a GPU.

---

By now the [password hashing competition](https://password-hashing.net/) has finished and it has supplied some interesting alternatives such as the winner, Argon2.